# django heroku amazon s3 bad request (400)

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3

I have recently published a website on heroku using django and amazon s3 for static files.

The website loads ok, but when I visit some pages of my website I get a bad request (400) error message.

Here is the heroku error log:

```
2018-03-15T11:58:26.542380+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/%CE%B5%CF%80%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%BF%CE%B9%CE%BD%CF%89%CE%BD%CE%AF%CE%B1/" host=matakiaslifts.herokuapp.com request_id=71c7000e-7f30-440e-8993-0cea19cd94d5 fwd="2.86.82.62" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=36ms status=400 bytes=286 protocol=https

2018-03-15T11:40:23.414590+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.225.52.12 - - [15/Mar/2018:11:40:23 +0000] "GET /%CE%B5%CF%80%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%BF%CE%B9%CE%BD%CF%89%CE%BD%CE%AF%CE%B1/ HTTP/1.1" 400 26 "https://matakiaslifts.herokuapp.com/%CE%B5%CE%B3%CE%BA%CE%B1%CF%84%CE%AC%CF%83%CF%84%CE%B1%CF%83%CE%B7/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.162 Safari/537.36"
```

I have already checked my ALLOWED_HOSTS to include my app's url on heroku.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the problem... I opened my heroku app with debug=True in my django settings. After visiting the problematic pages I saw a 'SuspiciousOperation: Attempted access to ... denied' django exception so I just updated the path that was leading to my static files by removing the forward slash in the beginning.